# Where does the energy go in inelastic collisions?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, energy, energy-conservation, collision, dissipation

Chabay and Sherwood write in [Matter and Interactions](https://matterandinteractions.org/) on page 406 about sticking collisions:

> We'll consider an inelastic collision in which a truck and a car collide in an icy intersection and stick together [...]
>
> Part of the energy was radiated away as sound waves in the air,
> produced when the vehicles collided with a bang. Some of the energy
> went into raising the temperature of the vehicles, so that their
> thermal energy is now higher than before (larger random motions of the
> atom).
>
> Some of the energy went into deforming the metal bodies of the truck
> and car.

"Some of the energy" sounds like a little, so I did some research and the following graph

[image]

in [this](https://dx.doi.org/10.1088/1742-6596/1486/7/072014) paper.

So it seems that most of energy is converted to internal (i.e. plastic deformation) energy.

Now I am looking for other illustrating examples where distribution between the "dissipation paths" is different, for example on where the sound energy contributes most etc.

Please include a reference or a calculation into your answer which shows the distribution of the "dissipation paths" in your example.

Comment: Hard clipping of speakers might be a good place to look.  Speakers are designed to convert energy to sound, so they're going to be well shaped to convert that kinetic energy into sound energy.

Comment: I do not know well enough about this topic to be contributing an answer but consider looking into bells. When you bang a bell, practically the whole energy converts to sound and negligible heat energy and deformation is produced.

Answer (score 0):

An example in a very different context is in atomic and molecular collisions with surfaces. If I shoot an atom at a surface with some kinetic energy $T_i$ and it bounces off the surface with a kinetic energy $T_f < T_i$, we know that energy has been deposited into the surface. Typically this takes the form of phonons, which you can think of as quantum mechanical sound waves. If you shoot a molecule at the surface and it bounces off, you will find even more kinetic energy lost. This is because energy is dissipated into phonons *and* vibrations of the molecule (again analogous to sound). Molecules will often stick to a surface. In this case the initial energy is partitioned into phonon/vibration components, and a component that overcomes an activation barrier to form a chemical bond with the atoms of the surface.

In general, the energy in an inelastic collision can only go two places: transfer to the other colliding body, or a conversion to internal energy (electronic excitation, vibrations, deformations, etc. depending on context).